# RelativeLayout in TableRow

Tags: android, textview, tablerow, android-relativelayout

I would like to create a `TableRow` view that contains three `TextViews`.
Two of those `TextViews` should be placed above each other on the left side of the `TableRow`.
This works fine, however I'm not able to place the third `TextView` on the far right side of the `TableRow`.

The code is as follows, but doesn't do what I want.
What am I missing? Code is below.

```
    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/hoblerValues"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_prototype"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="19:13" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_time"
                android:text="11.06.2014" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="248.00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TextViews, text_time and text_date should both have

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

In the attributes for text_date

```
android:layout_below="@+id/text_time"
```

should be

```
android:layout_below="@id/text_time"
```

There's no need for

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

in the RelativeLayout.

Comment: thank you for your reply. your suggestions did not change anything. but adding $android:layout_weight="1"$ to the RelativeLayout declaration helped.